# PostgreSQL Поиск проверка наличия элемента массива в другом массиве

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть таблица, в которой есть столбец `id_resource` типа `bigint`, который является массивом идентификаторов другой таблицы. На сервер приходят данные в виде массива и необходимо проверить есть ли совпадения по значениям из пришедших данных и в этом столбце.

Пример:

```
Таблица 
id    id_resource
1    {1,2}
2    {5,6}
Пришли данные: [1,2,3,4] => Вернуть запись с id = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте оператор [`&&`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE):

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM t_1
 WHERE id_resource && ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4]
;
```